# How do I make sure that the Android keyboard does not compress the content?

Tags: react-native, expo

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSopd.png)

On iOS, everything works, the block is not pressed to the top. I can't solve the problem on android

Comment: Hi! Help me deal with the problem, on Android the keyboard presses the block to the top, I struggle with the problem I do not know how to win. I can pass the screen height to the block, but then you need to subtract the navigation height - but I don't know how to get it

Answer (score 0):

By default android native code maintains the soft input with the keyboard.

You have to do some changes to solve your problem.

open your **android manifest file** you can see the line in the application tag below

**android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"**

replace it with the below line:

**android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"**